# jq Multiple Arguments

Tags: json, jq

Given my JSON object in `data.json`:

```
{
    "prod": {
        "apps": {
            "myapp": {"cloudfront_id":"BINGO-PROD"}
        }
    },
    "stg": {
        "apps": {
            "myapp": {"cloudfront_id":"BINGO-STG"}
        }
    }
}
```

And given the following `jq` in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

ENV="prod"
APP="myapp"

OUTPUT=$(cat data.json | jq -rc \
--arg env "${ENV}" \
--arg app "${APP}" \
'.[$env] .apps .[$app] .bar')
```

This fails with the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.[$env] .apps .[$app] .cloudfront_id
jq: 1 compile error
```

if I remove only the `[$app]` and replace it with `myapp` it works fine. i'm running `jq-1.5` - any ideas why?

Comment: looks fine. can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I've updated the question with all the data that I have

Comment: Thanks. But `ENV="prod" APP="myapp"; jq -rc --arg env "${ENV}" --arg app "${APP}" '.[$env] .apps .[$app] .cloudfront_id' data.json` works fine here.

Comment: oh so you're getting a syntax error? try `.[$env] .apps [$app] .cloudfront_id` then.

Comment: Bingo! can you post an answer so i'll choose it? and how come dropping the `.` before the app var solves it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jq 1.5 doesn't support `.key.["key"]` syntax (1.6 does though). Drop the dot before `[$app]` and you're good to go:

```
.[$env].apps[$app].cloudfront_id
```